# BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range error (Error Number : 1690)

Tags: plugins, vbulletin

I'm getting this error when I try to delete a thread in vBulletin 4. This isn't a vBulletin issue as it is an add-on modification. Below is the code I am using. If they have, say, 15 words in the thread post and I delete the thread, I get the error even though it is 15 words that is being deleted, setting their word count back to zero, not a negative number.

```
$threadinfo = fetch_threadinfo($threadid); 
$postinfo = fetch_postinfo($threadinfo['firstpostid']); 
$userdm =& datamanager_init('User', $this->registry, ERRTYPE_SILENT); 
$userdm->set_existing($postinfo); 
$userdm->set('totalwords', 'totalwords - ' . str_word_count($postinfo['pagetext']), false); 
$userdm->save(); 
unset($userdm);
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$threadinfo = fetch_threadinfo($threadid); 
$postinfo = fetch_postinfo($threadinfo['firstpostid']); 
$userdm =& datamanager_init('User', $this->registry, ERRTYPE_SILENT); 
$userdm->set_existing($postinfo); 
$userdm->set('totalwords', 'totalwords' - . str_word_count($postinfo['pagetext']),   false); 
$userdm->save(); 
unset($userdm);
```